# wpf: tabitem header to fit header.content size

Tags: controls, tabs

I have a tab control and when there are too many itmes, I get tab item headers on multiple lines.
So it will be like

```
[TabItemAA1] [TabItemAA2]
[        TabItem3       ]
[TabItem4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA]
```

I don't mind them stacking but when this happens, TabItem3's header stretchs to fit the width of tab control. 
How can I prevent this or make the tab item content which is TextBlock to fit the extended width?

Thanks

Comment: Could you draw a picture (mspaint is fine) of what you are expecting to see? I've solved a similar sounding issue, by making a custom panel and modifying control templates. Your issue may be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kind of the way people expect to see it, though. The tab labels should be centered so you can easily read them. I assume you want to left or right justify instead. Changing the dominant UI paradigm is only a good idea if you're going to improve upon it.

It could get very messy, but you could nest another container inside the header and explicitly specify the size and alignment of the objects it contains.

For a different UI style where the tabs scroll horizontally instead of splitting into multiple lines, you could also check out this guy's article, titled "WPF Single Row Tab Control": http://rickdoes.net/post/2009/11/06/WPF-Single-Row-Tab-Control.aspx